# Cakephp 3 queryBuilder for many to many relations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query which i am executing directly using connection manager like

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$sizes = $connection->execute('SELECT s.name size_name, s.id size_id, tp.price
         FROM toppings t
         INNER JOIN `sizes` s on s.category_id =  t.category_id
         LEFT JOIN `toppings_prices` tp ON tp.topping_id = t.id AND tp.size_id = s.id
         WHERE t.id= :id', ['id' => $id])->fetchAll('assoc');
```

In this case `Sizes` and `Toppings` have many to many relation and the assocaitions are defined as per CakePHP 3 docu like in `ToppingTable` i have defined the relation like

```
$this->belongsToMany('Sizes', [
      'foreignKey' => 'topping_id',
      'targetForeignKey' => 'size_id',
      'joinTable' => 'toppings_prices'
    ]);
```

The above query is defined in ToppingsController's edit method.
Is there are better way to acive the same results as from the above query?

I have tried CakePHP standards like, which return all possible fields from all 3 tables which I actually don't want

```
$rs = $this->Toppings
     ->find()
     ->contain(['Sizes'])
     ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId]);
```

Comment: Have you tried via Cake standards yet, but just aren't getting the right results?  Please show attempt.

Comment: Something like, which return all possible fields from all 3 tables which I actually don't want


$rs = $this->Toppings
     ->find()
     ->contain(['Sizes'])
     ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId]);